# AngularJs Modal Dialog on part of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using a **Modal** from **AngularJs UI Bootstrap** explained from [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

I want the modal to show on a particular part of the page (in a specific DIV for example),
only blackening its container and not the full screen.

Here is the example,  I want the modal to show only on the lightblue part (`id="chat"`)
http://plnkr.co/edit/tEnmm7RDOiB6sag4ailo?p=preview

Comment: I don't see how it can be done without extending the directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally it is not possible as every modals created by AngularJs UI Bootstrap are happened to the html body. That being said there is always a way :)

**Disclaimer**: the following is kind of a hack and I will strongly recommend that you create your own directive.

Modal component exposes two promises one called **result** and the other one called **opened** . In our case we will use the 2nd one for knowing when the modal is opened and visible. From there we can append the modal to another div element as follow :

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        windowClass : 'uniqueClassName', //use to easily find the dom element
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: ChatModalController
    });
    modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
      $timeout(function(){
        var modalDom = document.querySelector('.uniqueClassName'); // The modal
        var modalBackDom = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop'); //The backdrop
        var chatDom = document.querySelector('#chat');

        chatDom.appendChild(modalDom); //Move modal & backdrop inside chat div
        chatDom.appendChild(modalBackDom);

      });
    })
```

In order to accomodate the new scenario we should also add/modify some css classes like that :

```
  #chat {position:relative;}
  #chat .modal,
  #chat .modal-backdrop{
    position : absolute;
  }
```

Finally you can see a working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZO36Hc?p=preview).